# Remove recent workspace on Eclipse IDE startup

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to remove a work-space from recent work-spaces on Eclipse IDE startup window?

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.zparacha.com/remove-eclipse-workspace-dropdown-list/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the Preferences go to the 'General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces' page where you can edit the list shown during startup. See below -

[image]

You can also set the number of workspace remembered and turn the list on/off.